# How to select range from selected row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select range from selected row. For example, when a user select row 2 - 5 in column B (=B2:B5), and run the macro, I want the selection to be B2:E5 .

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: You want the selection to be B2:E5 or E2:E5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer the same row but different column then you can use Range.Offset property.

expression.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)

For Ex: Range("B1").Offset(, 3 )

Refers to the value in same row that of 'B1' but column 'E'

And If you want to select range from E2:E5 then you have to just loop it.

Can I have your code? so that I can improve it.

Comment: Thanks! I use Offset function all the time in Excel but haven't thought of using it in vba. I actually achieved what I wanted to do by this code:

Comment: <Code>
FirstRow = Selection.Row
LastRow = Selection.rows.Count + FirstRow - 1


Range("U" & FirstRow, "AD" & LastRow).Select

Comment: could you tell me how to post code in grayed box in comment?

Comment: To put code in comments in a `gray box` you need to use the grave key (or backtick) ` to surround the code block